# Ext Js Tooltip to stay when hover over

Tags: animation, extjs, tooltip

I have a button at which when the user hovers over I display a tooltip.

```
function createTooltp(toolTipId) {
 tooTip = new Ext.ToolTip({
 target: toolTipId,            //The button
 anchor: 'left',
 autoWidth: true,
 autoHeight: true,
 closable: false,
 autoHide: true,
 autoHeight : true,
 closable: false,
 contentEl: 'content-tip'
 });
tooTip.show();
}
```

Now when the user hovers away obviously it would hide since I mentioned `autoHide:true,`.
But when the user hovers to the actual tooltip which is displayed. I want that tooltip to be there till the mouse is on top of it and hide when the mouse is not on the target(button) or on the actual tooltip. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score -9, accepted):

I did it with a work around (jQuery). And used Span and CSS to create my own tooltip.

Answer (score 13):

Don't rely on Ext to hide the tooltip for you (autoHide: false). Instead, start a delayed hide using window.setTimeout when you leave the tooltip target and when you leave the tooltip, but cancel the hide if you hover back over the tooltip. That way, it will only hide when you're not on the tooltip after 500ms.

```
var toolTip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: targetId,
    html: 'ToolTip',
    anchor: 'left',
    dismissDelay: 0,
    showDelay: 0,
    autoHide: false
});

toolTip.on('show', function(){

    var timeout;

    toolTip.getEl().on('mouseout', function(){
        timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
            toolTip.hide();
        }, 500);
    });

    toolTip.getEl().on('mouseover', function(){
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    });

    Ext.get(targetId).on('mouseover', function(){
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    });

    Ext.get(targetId).on('mouseout', function(){
        timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
            toolTip.hide();
        }, 500);
    });

});
```

Comment: this is a good design but there is a bug. You need to clear the timeout on mouseover of the target. If not when you close the tip by clicking anywhere else on the screen the timeouts do not get cleared. so if you go to hover again the tip will be closed < 500 - or whatever else delay you have set.

'code'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function createTooltp(toolTipId) {
    var tooTip = new Ext.ToolTip({
        target: toolTipId, // The button
        anchor: 'left',
        showDelay: 0,
        hideDelay: 0,
        trackMouse: true
    });

    tooTip.show();
}
```

Learn more from this reference: [ToolTip](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Manual:Widgets:ToolTip)

Comment: In the list of items. DismissDelay would not work. As it would hold the tooltip for 15 seconds while the user might be on different item.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: I had task to add same behavior for tooltips inside grid panel columns, and it doesn't have way to pass config or tooltips inside it (or maybe I missed it in the docs and while reading sources, please comment if I had). So I solved it by adding small override to my app

```
Ext.define('App.overrides.ToolTip', {
    override: 'Ext.tip.ToolTip',
    dismissDelay: 0
});
```